# Navigating maps using iterators in c++

Tags: c++

I've been having an issue using the map iterator, which I'm hoping someone here can resolve for me.

Basically, I need to return the last 10 keys in a map that I have, so I tried this:

```
for (map<int, char>::iterator i = (singleCountSwitched.end()); i != (singleCountSwitched.end()-10); --i) {
                cout << (*i).first << ": " << (*i).second << endl;
            }
```

However it is giving me the following error:

```
main.cpp:150:112: error: no match for ‘operator-’ in ‘singleCountSwitched.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::end<int, char, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, char> > >() - 10’
```

which seems to say that there is no support for the - operator (a similar message was thrown when using map.begin()+10). Am I using the iterator incorrectly? I thought the iterators for STL containers were supposed to all have overloaded +'s and -'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map<int, char>::reverse_iterator r_it_end = singleCountSwitched.rbegin();
map<int, char>::reverse_iterator r_it_begin = singleCountSwitched.rbegin();
std::advance(r_it_begin, 10);
```

you can also use advance of normal iterator with (size() - 10)

i think this is a better one

```
map<int, char>::reverse_iterator r_it_begin = singleCountSwitched.rbegin();
std::advance(r_it_begin, 10);

for (map<int, char>::iterator it = r_it_begin.base(); it != singleCountSwitched.end(); ++it)
{
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your solution - how do I use it in a loop, if that's what you're implying I should do? I've never used the advance function before, so I'm not entirely sure how to use it in a for loop.

Comment: i have added another example with a loop

Answer (score 0):

Looks like map::iterator is a bidirectional iterator which supports increment/decrement but not arithmetic addition/subtraction of some int (compared with random access iterator which does support the latter).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/end/

Why not just decrement 10 times?

Comment: Weird to not be a random access iterator.. Vector definitely has arithmetic manipulation. Thanks for the link!